# Отсылка к Версальскому театру, с прописной, есть такой?

Tags: прописная-строчная

> Помимо нескольких неплохих ресторанов и кинотеатра, где проходит
> фестиваль американского кино, отель владеет театром (точным ремейком
> Версальского), где идут театрализованные шоу, и собственно казино.

Нашла только одно упоминание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, обнаружить Версальский театр, тогда я буду знать, что в процитированном тексте прописная на месте.

СПАСИБО!

Comment: Пока насчёт запятой перед первым И. Не пойму, зачем она?

Comment: Разве не об этом речь: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F?

Comment: Тёмыч, ошибка, спасибо! Это первая корректура - я сосредоточилась на другом. Убираю, чтобы не позориться.

Comment: Вики не об этом. Королевская опера Версаля, если её обозвать версальским театром, хотя в Версале театров не один, будет со строчной - по причине ни одного не сохранённого слова из полного официального названия.

Comment: Вряд ли прописная там на месте. А "собственно" там в контексте нормально смотрится?

Comment: Спасибо, Гриззли, это я автору отправлю. Возможно, далее последует какие-то сокрушительные откровения именно про казино... Но спрошу непременно.

Comment: Похоже, Вы правы: если вообще не очень важно разобраться, о каком именно театре речь, и не надо о нём ничего узнавать, остаётся только действительно исправить на маленькую букву. Я пошукал и не нашёл ничего похожего на театр, который бы назывался Версальским. На 99% в тексте речь о театре Монтансье.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Речь, скорее всего, идет о [Версальском театре "Монтансье"](http://www.turizm.ru/france/versal/places/teatr_montanse/):

Приглашённые на открытие театра зрители были поражены великолепной отделкой зала. Он был изысканно оформлен *в нежных бело-голубых оттенках при обильном использовании позолоченных декоративных элементов.* При всём этом золото не смотрелось помпезно, а отлично вписывалось в интерьер, придавая ему особую торжественность.

В статье [**Встречные гастроли Малого и Версальского театров**](http://archive.svoboda.org/archive/ll_cult/0801/ll.083001-2.asp)  читаем:

А театральное здание было построено в 1777-м году, так что Малый и Монтасье - почти ровесники. На открытии театра, который назвали "Большим Версальским", присутствовали Людовик XVI и Мария-Антуанетта. В 1936-м году театр переименовали в "Монтасье".

Так что, думаю, ошибки в названии *Версальский* не будет.